# Excel Pivot table subtotal with element exclusion

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, subtotal

I want to add the extra line of Grand Total of the pivot table,
which excludes some element group. Is it possible to do this?

For example, I want to add subtotal of **[East excluded New York Total]**, 
is it possible without adding the additional column for grouping purpose from the source data/worksheet?

Because I further want **[East + West Total]** 
and **[East excluded New York + West Total]**. The approach of adding extra group label columns is not flexible enough as the group subset is not static (i.e., New York sometimes is a subset of East, sometimes not, 
for showing subtotal). Thanks.

eg.

```
East
  New York                     100
  Boston                       200
  Philadelphia                 300
[East excluded New York Total] 500
East Total                     600
West
  XXX                          999
  YYY                          999
  XXX                          999
West Total                     999
---------------
[East excluded New York + West Total] 999
GrandTotal                    9999
```

Answer (score 0):

> Presuming the cities are in Column `A` and start with `A2` and ends wit `A5`, then resulting cell will be:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A5, <>"New York", B2:B5)
```

will do the trick. 
Though to be noted, pivot tables were never intended to yield extra rows and it may actively hurt your table structure.

Easiest solution to not get interfering dynamic ranges would be to treat East Coast and Web Coast as seperate Pivot Field Columns instead of Field Rows.

This way, you can apply the formula to entire `[@Column]`